# I can't import dotenv from python-dotenv

Tags: python, django, python-dotenv

Windows, Visual studio, django. I tried to install python-dotenv:
https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/#getting-started.

But when I want to import this command, I get error:
Import "dotenv" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports.

I made such imports:
(venv) PS C:\Users... pip3 install python-dotenv
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in c:\users...\venv\lib\site-packages (0.19.0).

But import doesn't work. What can be wrong?

Comment: https://prntscr.com/1qd1bj8 - problem is in link.

Comment: does `pip list` show you dotenv?

Comment: yes, shows: python-dotenv 0.19.0

Comment: it seems, something was wrong with Visual studio or virtual environments. It started work after several computer restarts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your Python version if you have more than 1.
I got into trouble with the 3.10.0 and I changed it to 3.9.6.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Check if the Python interpreter VSCode is using is the one from your virtual environment (e.g. `myproject/venv/Scripts/python.exe`). You can read more about it on [the official VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31115214)

Comment: I deleted this answer a while ago, i dont know why it still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the Python path to the settings.json file in VScode.
Specifically, my .vscode folder contains "settings.json" where I added:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/path/to/python3"
```

Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem stems from the python interpreter you are using.

1. In VS Code, Go to **View > Command Palette > Python: Select interpreter**
2. Switch from the global to the recommended one

- Recommended: **Python 3.11.3('venv':venv) .\venv\Scripts\python.exe**
- Global: **Python 3.11.3 64 bit C:\Programs\Python3.11.3\python.exe**

**This worked for me.**